# Get row data in Laravel 5

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

I want to show data in bootstrap modal depending on the row that I clicked, but I always get the last value of the table even I click at another row

View:

```
@foreach (App\Model\Users::all() as $users)
<tr>
  <td>{{ $users->nama_depan }}</td>
  <td>{{ $users->nama_belakang }}</td>
  <td>{{ $users->email_user }}</td>
  <td>{{ $users->no_hp }}</td>
  <td>
    <a href="#"  data-href="{{ route('allusers.edit',$users->id_user) }}" data-target="#modaledit" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
    <a href="#" data-href="{{ route('delete-user', $users->id_user) }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modaldelete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
  </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Modal:

```
<div id="modaledit" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit User</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="InputEmail">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control"
            id="InputEmail" placeholder="Enter email" value=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="InputPassword">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control"
                id="InputPassword" placeholder="Password"/>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Route:

```
Route::resource('allusers','AllUsersController');
```

Controller:

```
public function edit($id_user)
{
  $users = \App\Model\Users::findOrFail($id_user);
  return view('all-users',compact('users'));
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#modaledit').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $(this).find('#InputEmail').attr('value', '{{ $users->email_user }}');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following changes:

View:

```
@foreach (App\Model\Users::all() as $users)
<tr>
  <td>{{ $users->nama_depan }}</td>
  <td>{{ $users->nama_belakang }}</td>
  <td class="emali_{{ $users->id_user }}">{{ $users->email_user }}</td>
  <td>{{ $users->no_hp }}</td>
  <td>
       <a href="#"  data-href="{{ route('allusers.edit',$users->id_user) }}" data-target="#modaledit" data-toggle="modal" data-id="{{ $users->id_user }}" ><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
       <a href="#" data-href="{{ route('delete-user', $users->id_user) }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modaldelete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
  </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

jQuery:

```
$('#modaledit').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var data_id = ($(event.relatedTarget).attr('data-id'));
    var email = $('.emali_'+data_id).text();
    $(this).find('#InputEmail').attr('value', email);
});
```

Comment: null value for data_id ? @Janotama

Comment: i remove console.log and it works!! Thanks for help @mith

Comment: Ok!! Thanks :) @Janotama